# lxml xpath can not handle <p> tag

Tags: html, lxml

How to get p tag text "Blahblah" in this situation :

when p tag text field is behind a strong tag, it can not be recognized by lxml.

```
<p class="user_p"><strong>cc</strong>Blahblah</p>
```

====code====

```
from lxml import html
content="""
    <div>
    <p class="user_p">Blahblah<strong>cc</strong></p>
    <p class="user_p"><strong>cc</strong>Blahblah</p> 
    </div>
"""
tree = html.fromstring(content.decode('utf-8'))

p = tree.xpath('//div/p')

print p[0].text

print p[1].text
```

====output====

```
Blahblah
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this HTML fragment,

```
<p class="user_p"><strong>cc</strong>Blahblah</p>
```

the text "Blahblah" is the value of the [`tail`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#tail) property of the `<strong>` element.

Demo code:

```
from lxml import html

content = """
    <div>
     <p class="user_p"><strong>cc</strong>Blahblah</p> 
    </div>"""

tree = html.fromstring(content)
s = tree.xpath('//div/p/strong')
print s[0].tail
```

Output:

```
Blahblah
```

Comment: You are correct. I also find another way: "//div/p/strong/following-sibling::text()". It could also fetch it out. Added for reference